# Use Line2D to plot line in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the data:

```
x = [10,24,23,23,3]
y = [12,2,3,4,2]
```

I want to plot it using [`matplotlib.lines.Line2D(xdata, ydata)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#module-matplotlib.lines). I tried:

```
import matplotlib.lines
matplotlib.lines.Line2D(x, y)
```

But how do I show the line?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should add the line to a plot and then show it:

```
In [13]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [15]: from matplotlib.lines import Line2D      

In [16]: fig = plt.figure()

In [17]: ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

In [18]: x = [10,24,23,23,3]

In [19]: y = [12,2,3,4,2]

In [20]: line = Line2D(x, y)

In [21]: ax.add_line(line)
Out[21]: <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f4c10732f60>

In [22]: ax.set_xlim(min(x), max(x))
Out[22]: (3, 24)

In [23]: ax.set_ylim(min(y), max(y))
Out[23]: (2, 12)

In [24]: plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I get a `can not put single artist in more than one figure` error when adding a line coming from another plot to `ax`

Answer (score 10):

The more common approach (not exactly what the questioner asked) is to use the *plot* interface. This involves Line2D behind the scenes.

```
>>> x = [10,24,23,23,3]
>>> y = [12,2,3,4,2]
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot(x,y)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f407c1a8ef0>]
>>> plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this problem when trying to replicate a line on two different plots.
(mentioned in a comment "cannot put single artist in more than one figure)
So assuming you already have a Line2D object from some other source and need it on new plot, the best way to add it to your plot is with:

```
line = Line2D(x, y)
plt.plot(*line.get_data(), ...)
```

You can also get a lot of the line's properties from its other "get" methods, [found here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.get_aa).