# Unable to plot Line2D object to axes in matplotlib 3.5.1

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, axes

I'm trying to extract lines (as `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` objects) from some individual axes (as `matplotlib.axes.Axes` object) and plot it on a different plot (with say subplots). I'm trying to use `Axes.add_line()` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688210/use-line2d-to-plot-line-in-python) function to achieve this as shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

figS = Figure(figsize=(15, 5))
figC = Figure(figsize=(15, 5))
figT = Figure(figsize=(15, 5))
yS = np.sin(t)
yC = np.cos(t)
yT = np.tan(t)
axS = figS.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
lS = axS.plot(t, yS)
axC = figC.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
lC = axC.plot(t, yC)
axT = figT.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
lT = axT.plot(t, yT)


supSFig, axsSF = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(15, 15))
axsSF[0].add_line(lS)
axsSF[1].add_line(lC)
axsSF[2].add_line(lT)
```

But I get the following Warning/Error:

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Passing argument *line* of unexpected type list to add_line which only accepts <class 'matplotlib.lines.Line2D'> is deprecated since 3.5 and will become an error two minor releases later.
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [79], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 supSFig, axsSF = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(15, 15))
----> 2 axsSF[0].add_line(lS)
      3 axsSF[1].add_line(lC)
      4 axsSF[2].add_line(lT)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:2279, in _AxesBase.add_line(self, line)
   2275 """
   2276 Add a `.Line2D` to the Axes; return the line.
   2277 """
   2278 self._deprecate_noninstance('add_line', mlines.Line2D, line=line)
-> 2279 self._set_artist_props(line)
   2280 if line.get_clip_path() is None:
   2281     line.set_clip_path(self.patch)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:1101, in _AxesBase._set_artist_props(self, a)
   1099 def _set_artist_props(self, a):
   1100     """Set the boilerplate props for artists added to Axes."""
-> 1101     a.set_figure(self.figure)
   1102     if not a.is_transform_set():
   1103         a.set_transform(self.transData)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_figure'
```

I understand from the date mentioned in the post which I [referred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688210/use-line2d-to-plot-line-in-python) that it was possible in earlier versions and is a deprecated feature now. I'm using `matplotlib` version `3.5.1`.
How do I achieve the same functionality now? Is there a workaround or any newer feature to plot line object into axes object?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of reading, I happened to come across [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/line_with_text.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-line-with-text-py) doc. As mentioned in the title ***Artist within an artist***, the above error basically is the result of a restriction somewhere. The error is not an obvious one, so according to the example, we need to:

> Override basic methods so an artist can contain another artist.

Hence, adding the following would help:

```
import matplotlib.lines as lines
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
import matplotlib.text as mtext

class CustLine(lines.Line2D):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # we'll update the position when the line data is set
        self.text = mtext.Text(0, 0, '')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # we can't access the label attr until *after* the line is
        # initiated
        self.text.set_text(self.get_label())

    def set_figure(self, figure):
        self.text.set_figure(figure)
        super().set_figure(figure)

    def set_axes(self, axes):
        self.text.set_axes(axes)
        super().set_axes(axes)

    def set_transform(self, transform):
        # 2 pixel offset
        texttrans = transform + mtransforms.Affine2D().translate(2, 2)
        self.text.set_transform(texttrans)
        super().set_transform(transform)

    def set_data(self, x, y):
        if len(x):
            self.text.set_position((x[-1], y[-1]))

        super().set_data(x, y)

    def draw(self, renderer):
        # draw my label at the end of the line with 2 pixel offset
        super().draw(renderer)
        self.text.draw(renderer)
```

Now, all that needs to be done is replace the following:

```
supSFig, axsSF = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(15, 15))
axsSF[0].add_line(lS)
axsSF[1].add_line(lC)
axsSF[2].add_line(lT)
```

with:

```
supSFig, axsSF = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(15, 15))
axsSF[0].add_line(CustLine(lS[0].get_xdata(), lS[0].get_ydata()))
axsSF[1].add_line(CustLine(lC[0].get_xdata(), lC[0].get_ydata()))
axsSF[2].add_line(CustLine(lT[0].get_xdata(), lT[0].get_ydata()))
```

This works well and seems like the best way to pass lines to `Axes.add_lines()` method for `matplotlib` `v3.5+`. Any other workarounds are welcome too.

**P.S.:** Please note that `xdata` and `ydata` are mandatory arguments.